# For cars, what verb has to be used? Stehen oder liegen?

Tags: verb, usage

I'm highly confused with what verb should be used with automobiles. If I consider the car "stands" then *stehen* but it's in a horizontal position, so I suppose it could be *liegen* as well.

Comment: Welcome to the German Language SE. Please take your time and take the [tour] or browse through the [help].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well what comes in my mind at first are these option:

abstellen, parken und stehen/stehen lassen.

So it depends on the context:

If you want to express that **your car** is (standing) in a location as for example you say my car is parked in X-Street:

> Mein Auto steht in der Goethestraße.
>
> Mein Auto steht vor der Goethestraße 9.
>
> Mein Auto ist in der Goethestraße geparkt/abgestellt.

But if you want to express that **you** left your car (standing) somewhere then it's primary the other options that would fit.

Here some examples:

> Ich habe mein Auto neben der Metzgerei abgestellt!
>
> Ich habe mein Auto am Straßenrand geparkt.
>
> Ich habe mein Auto vor der Haustür stehen lassen.

---

**Special case** mentioned in the helpful comments of *Matthias* and *PattaFeuFeu* and also in *Hubert*s great answer:
Well as my first impression about the Question was the normal state a working car that stands or is parked somewhere, i didn't mention the options that may allow using the verb "liegen" or "liegen bleiben".
So after a car breakdown one could say:

> Ich bin mit meinem Auto liegen geblieben
>
> Mein Auto ist nach einem Motorschaden liegen geblieben

But in case of an accident when the car doesn't stand anymore on its wheels one also could use *liegen*:

> Nach dem Zusammenprall lag mein Auto auf der Seite im Straßengraben.

An other special case are toy-cars who may **lay** scattered in the room as *Stephie* mentioned in her helpful comment:

> Die Spielzeugautos (Autos) meines Sohnes liegen überall im Wohnzimmer herum.

Comment: Oh alright , so it basically depends on the circumstances as well...but if a car is generally standing on the road ,we use stehen

Comment: Well if you want a general option stehen is used if the car stands on its wheels liegen only in the case the car ended upside down or sideways (for example after an accident)

Comment: So should we consider the car like an animal (a modern horse)? With that analogy, the use of _liegen_ / _stehen_ seems logical.

Comment: @PierreArnaud i can't really follow this analogy, why should we and when should we use liegen for a horse?

Comment: Usually, a horse stands - like the car ("das Auto steht vor dem Haus"). An injured/dead horse does not stand - and a car after an accident doesn't either ("das Auto liegt zerstört vor dem Haus").

Comment: @PierreArnaud thanks, now i see the analogy you meant!

Answer (score 8):

A car has wheels. If it is not moving, and all wheels (but nothing else) are touching the ground, then you say:

> Das Auto **steht** auf der Straße.
>   The car **stands** on the street.

After an accident the car can end sideways or upside down. So non or at least not all of its wheel touch the ground, but other parts (door, roof) touch the ground. In this case you can say:

> Das Auto liegt auf der Seite.
>   The car is lying on it's side.
>
> Das Auto liegt am Dach.
>   The car is lying on it's roof.

But there is another term, that is similar to »liegen« (to lie). This is »liegen bleiben« (literal: to stay lying). For vehicles this means that you car's engine is broken, or you ran out of gas, or you lost a wheel, and therefore you can't drive any longer with it. To be precise: It means, that for technical reasons, but without having an accident, you suddenly can't drive the car any longer.

> Mein Wagen ist oben im Wald **liegen geblieben**, und ich musste den Weg hierher zu Fuß gehen. Er **steht** jetzt auf einem Forstweg.
>   My car broke down up there in the woods, and from there I had to walk all the way to come here. It **stands** now on a forest road.

Comment: Gut erklärt. Das einzige, was noch fehlt, ist die Betrachtung von Sätzen wie "Das Auto liegt gut / sicher / satt auf der Straße". Ach ja, und: "auf dem Dach", nicht "am Dach" (oder sagt ihr das in Österreich wirklich so?).

Comment: @Matthias: »am« ist sowohl »an dem« wie auch »auf dem«. Daher: »Wir machen Urlaub *am* Land, und zwar *am* Bauernhof« und »Die Butter steht *am* Tisch.« Mir war bis jetzt nicht bewusst, dass das in Deutschland anders ist.

Comment: @Matthias nach Hubert's Kommentar ist mir beim genauen reinhören in dem aktuellen "Hit" von Seiler und Speer auch aufgefallen, dass dort der Satz "*Wei aum Tisch is a Briaf gleng*" eher wie "*am Tisch*" aussprechen http://www.songtexte.com/songtext/seiler-und-speer/ham-kummst-4366afa3.html

Comment: @Medi1Saif: Der von dir angesprochene Songtext ist in einem Dialekt verfasst, nämlich in dem von Bad Vöslau, wo Seiler und Speer herkommen. Bad Vöslau liegt nur ca. 40 km von Wien entfernt, also geht dieser Dialekt noch als Wiener Dialekt durch. Das von mir verwendete »am« habe ich aber nicht in einem Dialekt-Kontext verwendet, sondern in einem hochdeutschen Satz. Dass es eine gleiche Konstruktion in einem Dialekt gibt, ist zwar nett zu wissen, belegt aber noch keinesfalls, dass die hochdeutsche Verwendung korrekt ist.

Comment: (Fortsetzung): Als Belege sind veröffentlichte hochdeutsche Texte besser geeignet. Wie z.B.: ”Urlaub am Bauernhof“: http://www.urlaubambauernhof.at/?L=1 oder http://urlaub.salzburgerland.com/de/sommerurlaub/Urlaub-am-Bauernhof_pa_2077 oder http://www.bergfex.at/oesterreich/pauschalangebote/urlaub-am-bauernhof/ In Wien gibt es auch ein »Kino am Dach«: http://volxkino.at/kino-am-dach/

Comment: @HubertSchölnast wie gesagt beim hören dachte ich nur habe ich nicht gerade so etwas gelesen habe. Danke für die Erläuterung!